# Is it possible to lock a file as a different user in Subversion?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have been assigned the creation of lots of hooks for our Subversion setup.  Among these are lock hooks.  Is it possible to lock a file as a different user than myself?  I need to be able to test lock hooks as more than one user.  We are using VisualSVN Server.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the passwords of the corresponding user you can use

```
svn lock --username other_user --no-auth-cache <file_to_lock>
```

SVN will ask you for the password. The **--no-auth-cache** avoids storage of the password in SVNs pw storage.
You can also use **--password**, if you want to write the password into the command.